# XML Serialize property with datatype as Array in C# .net

Tags: c#

I have Property

```
public Array Data
    {
        get;
        set;

     }
```

But I can't serialize it since type Array is not serializable, any Idea how can I achieve this,

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it more information; the simplest it to give it the typed array - for example, with a string array:

```
public string[] Data {get;set;}
```

It *may* (unsure) be possible to send untyped single-dimenstion arrays using `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem]` to specify the type - but by the time you've done that a typed array would have been easier. I doubt that multi-dimensional arrays are supported.

Comment: I can't since the Data type is unkwonn thats why I kept it as Array

Comment: @BreakHead: How about `Object[]` then? or a collection like `List<Object>`??

Comment: @BreakHead @decyclone `XmlSerializer` is a typed serializer; it cannot [de]serialize data unless the type is predictable. There are some ways around this if you simply have a *restricted* set of types, rather than "anything". If the type is actually known to be one of a finite set of possibilities, then please say

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<T>` where `T` is the type of object in your array. Then it will be able to serialize because it knows the Type of object. I believe it serializes like this:

```
<ArrayOfType>
 <Type>
  <X>value</X>
  <Y>value</Y>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <X>value</X>
  <Y>value</Y>
 </Type>
</ArrayOfType>
```